# One to One mapping's mappyBy attribute creates Exception : cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I had already googled but i found this issue(simultaneously Multiple bags) due to collections in entity.I am not able to found the root case.

Two entities has oneToOne mapping in each entities.
When i put mapped by attribute in one entity it creates  cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags issue.

If i remove mappedBy attribute then code works fine.

below is the code sample

Class A.java

```
@OneToOne
private B b;

@OneToOne
private C c;
```

Class B.java

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="b")  
private A a;
```

[EDITED]
Below is the latest signature of Class A & B. Now also it works . 
But if i add mapped By for type A in Class B , then the exception occurs.

Class A.java

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private B b;

@OneToOne
private C c;
```

Class B.java

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
private A a;
```

Exception is still there, No idea about why ?. Currently in that OneToOne mapping foreign key of each other entity is maintained in each entity. To reduce the maintaining of foreign key in both places , i used mapped by attribute in one entity but it throws the exception. That is the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

In A class it should be like this

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="b_id")
private B b;
```

In class B it should be

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="b")  
private A a;
```

It means that class A has a column b_id which references Class B's ID. And class B's object a we are just creating the backward reference.

Comment: By default in OneToOne mapping , join column will be added in the name of variable. If you want to override column name in table then @joinColumn is necessary.

Comment: Correct but your @OneToOne(mappedBy="a")  is wrong, just for a understanding purpose i added it.

Comment: Exception is still there, No idea about why ?. Currently in that  OneToOne  mapping foreign key of each other entity is maintained  in each entity. To reduce the maintaining of foreign key in both places , i used mapped by attribute in one entity but it throws the exception. That is the issue now.

Comment: Can you attach an exception?